# Equivalent of query-replace-regexp for multiple regexps

Tags: replace, query-replace-regexp

How can I do the equivalent of `query-replace-regexp` for multiple regexps?

For instance, if *regexp1* is matched, it should be replaced by *text1*, and if *regexp2* is matched, it should be replaced by *text2* (with interactive confirmation as with `query-replace-regexp`). The search and replace needs to be done in one pass for all the regexps (I don't want to use `query-replace-regexp` on the first regexp, then on the second regexp, and so on).

While querying could be done with a single regexp like `regexp1\|regexp2`, I don't know how I could do the replacement depending on whether *regexp1* or *regexp2* is matched. When `query-replace-regexp` is called interactively, `\,` can be used to execute a Lisp expression, which could do the selection, but this is not possible for code put in my `.emacs`, for instance.

Comment: Note that you might get different results depending on the order of the replacements. IMO it is somewhat dangerous to try to do more than one, so I do them one at a time and check in-between to make sure that I got what I wanted.

Comment: @NickD In my case, I make sure that there cannot be any overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  Enter an empty regexp interactively to stop adding regexp/replacement pairs, and start replacements.

```el
(defun query-multi-replace-regexp (&rest pairs)
  "Query replace for each regexp and replacement string in PAIRS."
  (interactive
   (let (pairs regexp replacement)
     (while (and (setq regexp (read-regexp "Query replace regexp"))
                 (not (string= regexp "")))
       (push regexp pairs)
       (push (read-string (format "Query replace regexp %s with: " regexp))
             pairs))
     (nreverse pairs)))
  (let ((pos pairs)
        patterns)
    (while pos
      (push (pop pos) patterns)
      (pop pos))
    (perform-replace
     (concat "\\(?:" (mapconcat 'identity patterns "\\|") "\\)")
     (cons (lambda (pairs count)
             (catch 'replacement
               (while pairs
                 (let ((regexp (pop pairs))
                       (string (pop pairs)))
                   (when (string-match-p regexp (match-string 0))
                     (throw 'replacement string))))))
           pairs)
     :query :regexp nil)))
```

See the definition of `query-replace-regexp` if you want to support things like replacement in a region.  It shows how to obtain the arguments for `perform-replace`.

Comment: This works well with simple replacements, but has an issue with capture groups. For instance, instead of `(query-multi-replace-regexp "te\\(\\w*\\)" "A-\\1-" "\\(..\\)fer" "B-\\1-")`, one needs `(query-multi-replace-regexp "te\\(\\w*\\)" "A-\\2-" "\\(..\\)fer" "B-\\1-")` here. Worse than that, because of this issue, one quickly reaches the limit of 9 capture groups (for my needs, each regexp can have up to 5 capture groups).

Comment: This actually seems to work with explicitly numbered groups, by reusing the number from 1: `(query-multi-replace-regexp "te\\(?1:\\w*\\)" "A-\\1-" "\\(?1:..\\)fer" "B-\\1-")`. There's no ambiguity, so that this is safe. I'll do some more tests.

Comment: I suspect that's safe, yes.  `C-h i g (elisp)Regexp Backslash` says that "you can have several groups with the same number in which case the last one to match (i.e., the rightmost match) will win."

Comment: You can alternatively test changing `string-match-p` to `string-match` without the `-p` suffix.  They're the same, except that the former does *not* change the match data, and the latter does.  I was intentionally not changing the match data to ensure that I didn't mess with anything `perform-replace` was doing, but it might (a) be fine and (b) address your issue.  Untested by me.